# How should I set the return type of asList in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, collections

[image]
I am studying while changing the code written in `Java` to `Kotlin`.

But I am confused about `List collection` using `Arrays.asList` in `Java`.

When I set the return type to `List<String>`, `asList` throws an error.

In the documentation of `asList`, the return type is List, so why not allow it?

In the `IDE`, the solution is to change the return type to `MutableList<Array<String>>?` present..
`MutableList<Array<String>>?` What is the meaning of

Not just a MutableList, what does Mutable<ArrayList> mean?

`List`, `MutableList`, `ArrayList`.. I don't know which one to fit

***enum class***

```
enum class BodyType(_resourceId: Int) {
    CHEST(R.array.chest_workout_list),
    BACK(R.array.back_workout_list),
    LEG(R.array.leg_workout_list),
    SHOULDER(R.array.shoulder_workout_list),
    BICEPS(R.array.biceps_workout_list),
    TRICEPS(R.array.triceps_workout_list),
    ABS(R.array.abs_workout_list);

    @ArrayRes
    private val resourceId: Int = _resourceId


    fun getResourceId() : Int = resourceId
}
```

***interface***

```
interface WorkoutListSource  {
    fun getWorkoutListByPart(type: BodyType) : ArrayList<String>?
}
```

***WorkoutListLocalSource.kt***

```
class WorkoutListLocalSource(_resources: Resources) : WorkoutListSource {
    private val resource: Resources = _resources

    override fun getWorkoutListByPart(type: BodyType): ArrayList<String>? {
        Arrays.sort(resource.getStringArray(type.getResourceId()))
        return Arrays.asList(resource.getStringArray(type.getResourceId()))
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to return an `ArrayList` specifically? are you going to modify it?

Comment: No. I don't think there is any need to modify it since the purpose is to read data. The reason I used `arrayListOf` is simply because I am used to using it in `Java`.

Comment: Then just declare your `fun` to return `List<String>?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` is a Java stdlib function that takes a `vararg` set of parameters and turns them into a list. If you pass it an `Array<String>` like you're doing, it returns a `List<Array<String>>` of size 1.

To make it work with this Java standard library method, you need to use the spread operator `*`. I'm breaking this out into two lines to make it clearer.

```
val array = resource.getStringArray(type.getResourceId())
return Arrays.asList(*array)
```

In Kotlin, it's a little cleaner to use the Kotlin standard library function:

```
val array = resource.getStringArray(type.getResourceId())
return arrayListOf(*array)
```

If you didn't need ArrayList specifically and could return MutableList, it's simpler, but you'll need to redefine the interface function's return type:

```
return resource.getStringArray(type.getResourceId()).toMutableList()
```

Read-only Lists should be preferred over ArrayList/MutableList when you don't need to externally modify the list you're returning from whatever function is getting it. This is almost always the case if you follow good OOP principles. So if you change the interface's return type to `List`, you can use the Kotlin stdlib's `asList()` to get a List that wraps the array rather than copying it like `arrayListOf()`, `toMutableList()` or `toList()` do:

```
return resource.getStringArray(type.getResourceId()).asList()
```

Your other questions are answered [here in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types). But basically `(Mutable)List` means you can treat the type from Java as either a MutableList or read-only List. The compiler can't tell the difference because Java doesn't have read-only lists. Some Java methods return immutable Lists that throw exceptions when you try to mutate them. It's up to you to look at the documentation for that method to determine whether it's safe to treat it as MutableList.

Comment: Thanks. I used `arraylist` simply because I'm familiar with Java.

But now that I think about it, the purpose of the code I am writing now is simply to read data.

So, isn't it inappropriate to use `ArrayList` and `MutableList` here?

Comment: Yes, public functions that return a list should return a read-only List probably like 99% of the time or more. Otherwise, you're suggesting to consumers that there's some reason they may want to mutate the list, and technically you should be defensively protecting against bugs internal to the class that might arise from external classes modifying the list. Of course, we've lived with that risk in Java and other languages. But if the tools for better encapsulation are there, we should use them.

Comment: Even in Java, it's a little odd to return ArrayList instead of List. It shouldn't be relevant for outside classes to know what specific List implementation is being used. Oh, and one more tip: it's cleaner to avoid returning nullable values when there isn't a need. You can return an empty list to represent no data to return, so nullability isn't required here.

Comment: Just return `.asList()`, no?  No need to even do a copy.

Comment: I added that. I hadn't suggested it because of the interface requiring an ArrayList, but looks like OP is open to changing that.

Comment: What is the `OP`?

Comment: Original poster…that’s you.

Comment: Haha... I didn't know that meant. Thanks for the reply, I solved it thanks to you!